# Are there any feature in FACEBOOK that notify user about specific incoming event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have successfully built small web app to create event on behalf of facebook's user. Now,  I want user to get notification (world icon in facebook's bar at the top of the screen),say, 1 day prior to the event start_time. Are there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to send notifications to your APP users. Right now, this feature is in Beta and has some limitations and I'm not sure if you can control the notification timings and all.

You can take a look at [App Notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/) for more details.